# Looping through sub-dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge pandas data frame called *main_df* and I wanted to split it into ten sub-dataframes so that it would be easier to handle. To split the data frame I did the following:

```
df_split = np.array_split(main_df, 10)
```

Now I can call each subset by doing the following:

```
df_split[0].head(10)
df_split[1].head(10)
```

and so on...

However now I want to create a loop that does an action involving each sub-dataframe. I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
for x in df_split:
    df_split[x] = "some action"
```

Would this be the correct way of looping through each sub-dataframe of df_split with a for loop? Any suggestions or guidelines would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is in the implementation. When you iterate over `df_split` you are actually looping directly over dataframes, as you can see:

```
df_split = np.array_split(df, 2)
for x in df_split :
    print(type(x))

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

So basically don't try to index `df_split` with `x`, as it already is the dataframe. Simply do:

```
for x in df_split:
    x = "some action"
```

Answer (score 0):

df_split = np.array_split(main_df, 10)

for x in df_split:
    x= "some_action"

df_split[i] will give you an error because your are not using index to access splitted dataframe. You are directly using them as x.

Answer (score 0):

> Would this be the correct way of looping through each sub-dataframe of
>   df_split with a for loop?

No, your solution is incorrect. [`np.array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy-array-split) returns a `list` of sub-dataframes. `x` represents a dataframe in its own right, so `df_split[x]` makes no sense. Instead, use `enumerate`:

```
for idx, df_sub in enumerate(df_split):
    df_split[idx] = some_function(df_sub)
```